# Not able to fetch data from ElasticSearch

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch

Having a simple ES local cluster running at 6.8.3 version. The problem is i am able to insert the data by my SpringBoot server but not able to get it.
Its throwing error

```
    Suppressed: org.elasticsearch.client.ResponseException: method [POST], host [http://localhost:9200], URI [/customer/_search?typed_keys=true&max_concurrent_shard_requests=5&ignore_unavailable=false&expand_wildcards=open&allow_no_indices=true&ignore_throttled=true&search_type=dfs_query_then_fetch&batched_reduce_size=512&ccs_minimize_roundtrips=true], status line [HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error]
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"json_parse_exception","reason":"Current token (VALUE_NUMBER_INT) not of boolean type\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.ByteBufStreamInput@15e6a969; line: 1, column: 100]"}],"type":"json_parse_exception","reason":"Current token (VALUE_NUMBER_INT) not of boolean type\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.ByteBufStreamInput@15e6a969; line: 1, column: 100]"},"status":500}
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.convertResponse(RestClient.java:302) ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:272) ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:246) ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1613) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
        ... 92 common frames omitted
```

A very simple server I have,

Customer object

```
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document;

@Document(indexName = "customer")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Customer {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String age;

}
```

A simple controller

```
@RestController
public class CustomerController {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerDao customerDao;

    @PostMapping("/saveCustomer")
    public Customer saveCustomer(@RequestBody Customer customer){
        return customerDao.save(customer);
    }

    @GetMapping("/findAll")
    public Iterable<Customer> findAllCustomer(){
        return customerDao.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/findByName/{firstName}")
    public List<Customer> findByFirstName(@PathVariable String firstName){
        return customerDao.findByFirstName(firstName);
    }
}
```

And this is my POM dependency

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.learn</groupId>
    <artifactId>elastic</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>elastic</name>
    <description>Learn ElasticSearch</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<--PLus some other -->
```

Not able to understand why saving is working but not searching.

Comment: It would be great if you aslo share you Data access operation level class and Repositories also

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is in your Dao level and I offer two approach .

1. Elastic search repositories .

Create a repository for elastic search with argument of your model (index) name then add then auto weird your repository and use it prewritten queries like findAll and use them as your need how ever you can create your own queries or criteria's with aid of [String](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.operations.nativesearchquery), [Native](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.operations.nativesearchquery) or [Criteriabase](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.operations.criteriaquery) queries.

```html
@Repository
public interface YouRepositoryName extends ElasticsearchRepository<YOURMODELNAME, String> {}
```

```html
@Autowired
YourRepository repositoryEntity
```

2. Dsl based inside Elastic repository

With the aid of [supported](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.query-methods.criterions) query methods create your own queries. Consider following example which we used a method in Binder class which generates our query script with it conditional statements with language of String query then we pass it to our repository and execute the query.

```html
@Component
public class Binder {

      public String SearchCore(SequenceSearchDTO entity) {

        String query="";
        Double z=0.00;
        Long x=z.longValue();
        if(entity.getParentKnowledgeGroupId() != null && !entity.getParentKnowledgeGroupId().isEmpty() && !entity.getParentKnowledgeGroupId().equals("")){
            query= "[{\"query_string\": { \"query\" : \""+entity.getParentKnowledgeGroupId()+"\", \"fields\" : [ \"parentKnowledgeGroupId\" ] }}," ;
        }
        if(entity.getKnowledgeGroupId() != null && !entity.getKnowledgeGroupId().isEmpty() && !entity.getKnowledgeGroupId().equals("")){
            query=query+ "{\"query_string\" : { \"query\" : \""+entity.getKnowledgeGroupId()+"\", \"fields\" : [ \"knowledgeGroupId\" ]}},";
        }
        if(entity.getTerm() != null && !entity.getTerm().isEmpty() && !entity.getTerm().equals("")){
            query=query+ "{\"query_string\" : { \"query\" : \""+entity.getTerm()+"\", \"fields\" : [ \"content\" ]}},";
        }
        if(entity.getPrice() != null && ! entity.getPrice().equals("")){
            query=query+"{\"range\" : {\"price\" : {\"from\" :"+x+" , \"to\" : "+entity.getPrice()+", \"include_lower\" : true, \"include_upper\" : true } } },";
        }

        if(entity.getCourseType() != null && ! entity.getCourseType().equals("")){
            query=query+ "{\"query_string\" : { \"query\" : \""+entity.getCourseType()+"\", \"fields\" : [ \"courseType\" ]}},";
        }
        if(entity.getScore() != null && ! entity.getScore().equals("")){

            query=query+"{\"range\" : {\"scoree\" : {\"from\" : "+0+", \"to\" : "+entity.getScore()+", \"include_lower\" : true, \"include_upper\" : false } } },";
        }
        if(entity.getBeginDate() != null && ! entity.getBeginDate().equals("")){

            if(entity.getEndDate() != null && ! entity.getEndDate().equals("")) {
                query = query + "{\"range\" : {\"LogicalDate\" : {\"from\" : " + entity.getBeginDate().getTime() / 1000 + ", \"to\" : " + entity.getEndDate().getTime() / 1000 + ", \"include_lower\" : true, \"include_upper\" : true } } },";
            }
            else{
                query=query+ "{\"range\" : {\"LogicalDate\" : {\"from\" : "+entity.getBeginDate().getTime()/1000+", \"to\" : "+new Date().getTime()/1000+", \"include_lower\" : true, \"include_upper\" : true } } },";
            }
        }
        if(entity.getDuration() != null && ! entity.getDuration().equals("")){
            query=query+"{\"range\" : {\"studyTime\" : {\"from\" :"+x+" , \"to\" : "+entity.getDuration()+", \"include_lower\" : true, \"include_upper\" : true } } },";
        }
        if(entity.getFree() != null){
            query=query+ "{\"query_string\" : { \"query\" : \""+entity.getFree()+"\", \"fields\" : [ \"free\" ]}}]";
        }

        return query;
    }

}
```

Create a supported query method like below

```html
@Repository
public interface SequenceRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<ElasticModelSequence, String> {

    @Query("{\"bool\":"+
            "{\"must\" :"+
            "?0"+
            "}"+
            "}")
    List<ElasticModelSequence> stringQuery(@Param("flag") String flag);

}
```

Finally make use of it in your Dao level

```html
List<ElasticModelSequence> flag=sequenceRepository.stringQuery(query);
```